# Execute code after page has finished loading javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

so I'm loading a url which takes a fairly long time to load, about a minute. I'm wondering how I should go about executing some additional javascript or jquery code only once the page has fully finished loading.

I was trying this but it was not working

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajaxSetup(
    {
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
            $('#div_loading').hide();
            $('#div_done').show();
        }
    });
    $.ajax("process.php?q=<?=$id?>&bitrate=<?=$bitrate?>");
});
```

Comment: Are you loading the process.php url with $.ajax above? It looks like you do not have any data returned, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [jQuery deferred](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) object e.g.

```
$.ajax("process.php?q=<?=$id?>&bitrate=<?=$bitrate?>").then(function(data){

});
```

Basically when the $.ajax call returns, the `then` function will be executed.